# Should I file taxes if I opened Amazon seller account but never used it?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, tax-deduction, state-income-tax, california

Me and my husband entered the US with F1(him) and F2(me) visas. He was a fully funded PhD student and we used to send our tax papers jointly. Last year we filed for EB2-NIW visa to get a Green Card, also an EAD card. In April(or maybe it was March) 2023, we received our EAD cards, also I got my SSN (He had the SSN since beginning but I didn't have).

Few months later (I believe it was in October 2023) I opened an Amazon seller account and a Google Adsense account, and I remember they asked me to confirm a tax form (I think it was w9 file) during the registration process. But I never used my Amazon seller account to sell anything, neither my Adsense account.

So I am wondering if we want to file our taxes for 2023, can we do it exactly like the previous year (because our job/income situation is exactly the same) or I must file separately for myself?
Also, should I file any extra documents because I received EAD card and SSN this year? Or because I opened Amazon seller account ot Google Adsense account even if I didn't use any of them?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you'll continue filing your taxes the same way as before. If you have SSN - it is now your tax id, and if you had ITIN before you should stop using it.

You'll need to evaluate your residency status (you might have been non-residents while on F visa, but are residents if you are green card holders, or you're in some in-between situation that needs to be addressed).

If you received any income from Google or Amazon, you'll need to declare it. If you had any business expenses related to that - you'll need to document it as well.

Comment: Thank you. I have also another question. If we guess we will receive our Green Cards in April 2024, is it better to wait to receive our Green Cards then file taxes or file it before getting Green Card?

Comment: I don't see how that matters, why do you ask?